# provider above openContainer of bulderFunctions

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, provider, changenotifier

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => BuyValuableNotifier(),
              child: OpenContainer(
              
                closedBuilder: (context, action) {
                  return Container();
                },
                openBuilder: (context, action) {
                  return SingleWidget();
                },
              ),
            ),
```

so I have this error when call openBuilder:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this SingleWidget Widget

```
OpenContainer(
              closedBuilder: (context, action) {
                return Container();
              },
              openBuilder: (context, action) {
                return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (context) => BuyValuableNotifier(),
                    child: SingleWidget();
              },
            ),
```

and if I do this I will loose data when openBuilder closes
what do I do?

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know I'm late but maybe I still help someone. The issue is that the builders of `OpenContainer` create a new context, so the returning widget of closedBuilder and openBuilder should be wrapped with `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` usually. This way you also wouldn't lose data when openBuilder closes because you'd be using the same provider instance.